# Is there a UnicodeCategory Enumeration diagram?

Tags: .net, unicode, diagram

I looking for a good [UnicodeCategory Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory%28VS.80%29.aspx) diagram that show an example to each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will Defines the Unicode category of a character.

A surrogate pair is a coded character representation for a single abstract character that consists of a sequence of two code units, where the first unit of the pair is a high-surrogate and the second is a low-surrogate. A high-surrogate is a Unicode code point in the range U+D800 through U+DBFF and a low-surrogate is a Unicode code point in the range U+DC00 through U+DFFF.

This enumeration is based on The Unicode Standard, Version 3.1

This enumeration is used to support Char methods, such as IsUpper

---

There is an Open Source Software at http://unicode.codeplex.com which get a Char and return Character Category.

These category mentioned on Unicode Character Database (annex #44) at http://www.unicode.org/ucd this database provide complete information about each charater including Character Category (and that open source software use this DB togive you the category )

---

Windows Charmap also will show you characters category.